# SQL Server 2008 Unpivot Converting Unknown # of Columns to Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Original:

```
EmpID     Week1     Week2    Week3...(Unknown unmber of weeks)
001       1         2        3
002       2         1        0
003       3         4        0
```

Target:

```
EmpID   Attibute    AttributeValue
001         Week1       1
001         Week2       2
001         Week3       3
002         Week1       2
002         Week2       1
002         Week3       0
003         Week1       3
003         Week2       4
003         Week3       0
             .
             .
             .
(will auto generate unknown # of weeks and their values)
```

I've done my homework, I haven't found a quesiton like this one. The only one I found similar is "[Dynamic SQL Server Pivot ( UNPIVOT ) column name to a row value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917108/dynamic-sql-server-pivot-unpivot-column-name-to-a-row-value)". I tried to run that query but the SQL Server returns no result and messages show "Command(s) completed successfully.)

Answer (score 2):

well, you can't have "unknown" number of columns in your table, but see [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx):

```
SELECT EmpID, Attibute, AttributeValue
FROM 
   (SELECT EmpID, Week1, Week2, Week3
   FROM pvt) p
UNPIVOT
   (AttributeValue FOR Attibute IN 
      (Week1, Week2, Week3)
)AS unpvt
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your table name is `Emp` and that you want to unpivot columns that matches `Week%`:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = 
  N'select EmpID, Attribute, AttributeValue from Emp unpivot (AttributeValue for Attribute in ('+
  stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('Emp') and
               C.name like 'Week%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')+
  N')) as U order by EmpID, Attribute'

exec (@SQL)
```