# Get ColumnHeader as row value and its associated values in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, union, pivot-table, common-table-expression

My table BankACTable:

```
BANK    ACNO    AC_SER      STATE  CITY
-----------------------------------------
ICICI   1220    0987654     MH      NGP
AXIS    4561    5786        AP      HYD
:       :       :           :       :
:       :       :           :       :
```

All that I want result in this form:

```
ColumnName              ColumnValue
-------------------------------------
AccountName             ICICI           
Amount                  1220
RegistrationNumber      0987654
State                   Maharashtra
Address                 Nagpur
AccountName             AXIS    
Amount                  4561
RegistrationNumber      5786
State                   AP  
Address                 HYD
```

All SQL heroes, plz help me to get this result!

Comment: Please check this StackOverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8919663/1928672

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNPIVOT` like this

```
SELECT COL,VAL
FROM (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),[BANK])[AccountName], CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),[ACNO]) [Amount], CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),[AC_SER]) as [RegistrationNumber], CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),[STATE])[State], CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),[CITY])[Address] 
      FROM BankAC) BankAC
UNPIVOT(VAL FOR COL IN ([AccountName], [Amount], [RegistrationNumber], [State], [Address])) as upvt;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c25f5/7)

**Output**

```
|                COL |    VAL |
|--------------------|--------|
|        AccountName |  ICICI |
|             Amount |   1220 |
| RegistrationNumber | 987654 |
|              State |     MH |
|            Address |    NGP |
|        AccountName |   AXIS |
|             Amount |   4561 |
| RegistrationNumber |   5786 |
|              State |     AP |
|            Address |    HYD |
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not `Pivot`, but an `Unpivot` operation

```
select 'icici' bank, 1220 acnum, '09876' ac_ser, 'mh111' state, 'ngp11' city
into #a
union
select 'axis' bank, 4561 acnum, '5786' ac_ser, 'ap' state, 'hyd' city

SELECT ColName, ColValue
FROM
(SELECT bank,  ac_Ser, [state], city
FROM #a) t
UNPIVOT
(ColValue for ColName in (bank,  ac_Ser, [state], city)
) AS val
```